# PHP to link radio buttons and check box values to junction tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have radio buttons and check boxes that I am trying to submit into a MySQL database using PHP.  My issue is that these are going into junction forms and I also need to include the text inserts as a value on the table.  Also, I honestly don't think I'm doing the radio buttons and check boxes right, something about Boolean structure?

I'm using MySQLi and just Notepad++.

My insert page has some radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="audience" value="Youth" />Youth 
<input type="radio" name="audience" value="Teen" />Teen
<input type="radio" name="audience" value="Adult" />Adult
```

and some check boxes:

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="1" />Action </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="2" />Adventure </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="3" />Comedy</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="4" />Coming of Age</td></tr>
```

This is the PHP I have for the radio buttons:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$audience= $_POST['audience'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO series (series_target_audience) VALUES 
('$audience')";
}
```

This code claims that it is working at this moment, but it is currently not actually depositing the values into the database at all.

Comment: You're not actually _running_ the SQL...

Comment: and if you were running it, you should not! This query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a connection to MySQLi and then prepare the statement, bind parameter and execute it.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $possibleRadioValues = ['Youth', 'Teen', 'Adult'];
    if(in_array($_POST['audience'], $possibleRadioValues, true)){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO series (series_target_audience) VALUES (?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['audience']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Also worth noting is that you should validate the data coming from your HTML form, as it might not be what you expect. In this case I used a white list of values in the array.

Comment: I apologize for not including it - I did link up to my database successful elsewhere in the PHP code, just didn't include it. But thank you fixing up the array for my radio buttons.  If you have any resources regarding check boxes - particularly check boxes that would populate multiple rows, that would be wonderful.  For example, the series may represent multiple genres, so I need have the end user check off Romance, Adventure, etc. and have them each populate a row in the junction table (along with the series_id which is a text field further up on the page)

Comment: What do you mean multiple rows? Keep in mind that only the active/checked checkboxes will be sent over to the server.

Comment: As in, the end user would be able to check off multiple check boxes and then each of these "checks" would insert as a new row in the junction table.

Comment: Do you mean that for each selected checkbox you want to insert new record into database?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I could only find code for counting check boxes or for limited checkboxes.

Comment: What is the relation of `series_target_audience` to `genre`? Do you mind giving an example or a row of values from your table?

Comment: No relation, really.  This is just a part of a large form that I cut down to the areas I was having trouble with.  Up top there is a text input for series_id that we comprise using our library's ID system. This series_id is used as a foreign key in a junction table that links the many to many relationship of series_id and genre_id. Therefore, I need to impose the genre_id (the actual that are set as their value) as well as the series_id to the junction table. For example:  series_id A8000, genre_id 1 (representing action), series_id A8000, genre_id 2, series_id A8000, genre_id 3, etc.

Comment: You could call `$stmt->execute()` in a loop. Wrap it in `foreach($_POST['genre'] as $checkbox)`, but I am not sure I follow you entirely. Your follow up question seems a little too broad. If you can narrow it down and explain with some examples, maybe you should ask a separate question?

Comment: sounds good. space is limited here, i will open another question if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Be sure to [go over the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to make sure your question is well received.